# C# How to get the size of the download file for showing the progressbar percentage

Tags: c#, curl, progress-bar

I'm using progressbar in c# but I got a bit of a problem I'm connecting to a server in our company and then I start to download an XML file from that 4k by 4k and showing this progress on a progressbar and for showing this if the file is below 100K till now then the maximum size of my progressbar would be 100 and if it changes I would change the maximum size of it to 1000 then 10000 and etc, so by this way I can doing this

```
progressbar1.value += 4;
```

So it's somehow working, but as all you know the right solution is to know the size of the file my connection is going to download before starting to download that. I think a little and I think using Curl maybe solve the problem, but I don't know exactly how to use it in C# or is there anyway to solve this problem.

Edit:
I'm downloading the file like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usr, pass);
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader s = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int lastIndex = 0;
            int readNum = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("start at : " + DateTime.Now);
            while (!s.EndOfStream)
            {
                readNum = s.ReadBlock(temp, 0, 4096);
                if (w != null)
                    w.incByVolume(4);
                ret += new String(temp);
                temp = new char[4096];
            }
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: "... I think using Curl maybe solve the problem...", now you've got two problems... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you load it with HTTP(S) you can use [`WebClient.DownloadFileAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196.aspx) which has all you need:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, args) =>
{
    //args.BytesReceived, args.TotalBytesToReceive and args.ProgressPercentage will have all you need
};
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, args) =>
{
    //done
};
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(remoteFile), localFile);
// or the following if you want it in memory:
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, args) => 
{
    //done, see args.Result for the string
};
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(remoteFile));
```

If you need credentials to acces the page, you can use the [`Credentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx) property of the WebClient.

According to the notes on [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx):

> By default, the .NET Framework supports URIs that begin with http:, https:, ftp:, and file: scheme identifiers.

So it would even work with loading the file from a share using the `file:` identifier.

Comment: And sorry for asking but what are the s and args parameters?

Comment: Actually that you suggested it's working fine when it's a File on the server but what about if you want to download from a page which is not a file for example it's a sever page which shows the current logs but it's not a file over there!

Comment: Thats just a short form of implementing the event handlers (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged.aspx) using a Lambda Expression. See this on all the ways you can subscribe to an event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx

Comment: Also you can just download a web page. DownloadFileAsync just downlaods the given resource (what ever it is, as long as it is accessible via HTTP(S)) to a local file. If you want to download it into your programs memory (like read the web page source in a string) you can e.g. use `DownloadStringAsync` (just check the availalbe methods in the `WebClient` class)...

Comment: I used the DownloadfileAsync and giving the url that I want to download and the name that I like it to be saved but it's creating the file but nothing in it... Could it be because the url that I'm accessing needs credential ??

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out the length (size) of the file before downloading, you have to read the Content-Length header in the HTTP response, it will provide the size of the file.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: but of course that is only true for a subset of the resources you'll ask for, as many pages are dynamically sized...

Comment: @DanielStenberg The OP didn't specify if the files are dynamically generated or not.